# Complicated mysql injection

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I'm trying to prove a point to on of my customers that the system is insecure against mysql injections. I would like have some evidence that either shows me a complete list (select * from..) of users or injects a new user/admin in the system so i am able to login afterwards.

This is a simplification of how the system i build:

PHP login site:

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

$query1 = "INSERT INTO user_log (username, password,ip) VALUES ('$user','$pwd','127.1.1.1')";

$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die("Query failed: "  . mysql_error());

$query2 = "select * from login where name = '$user' and pass = '$pwd' limit 1";

$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("Query failed: "  . mysql_error());
```

The mysql tables are something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_log` (
  `idadmin` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idadmin`)
)

CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `idlogin` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlogin`)
)
```

I find it very hard to inject on this even though I can see it is completely insecure.

1. The first thing I tried was injecting on the INSERT-query, but it was hard to get some decent results out of it other than spamming the user_log table.
2. I tried to make a query that went through the first query1 and injected at query2 instead. But this was quite complicated because of the quoting.

Any ideas or other kinds of techniques to make injection in this particular context?

Comment: You told your customer it is insecure before you figured how how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the customer is using an older version of PHP, less than version 5.4.0, and has mysql_quotes_gpc on then this is secure.

If you can run any type of SQL through user input, it's **INSECURE** and ugly! It's not a matter of whether you can figure out the exact type of attack that works, there is many creative ways an hacker could get what they want.

[Time based SQL injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512676.aspx) can be ran on the insert query, it wouldn't matter if the select query went through or not.

SQL Injection can allow an attacker to create files if the mysql user has the permissions. SELECT load_file('/etc/passwd') INTO OUTFILE '/some/path/to/web/root/here.php'

Comment: There is no gpc enabled. Ok your examples seems a bit too complicated for me to actually implement but your right: The point is not how to do it but that it is possible to extract information. I just hoped that there was an easy way to prove my accusation that this was insecure..

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to prove that you can see all user records in order to prove that the system is insecure.

If the code is running under `magic_quotes_gpc`, it should be fairly secure even as it is, though `magic_quotes_gpc` introduces all kinds of other problems.

<strike>If you're not running under `magic_quotes_gpc`, you should be able to log in with username `' or true; --` regardless of what password is supplied.</strike>

Comment: It would fail on the insert query.

Comment: True that, though this would not really qualify as "security". Still, one can inject their own user record either as custom `user` or `pwd` parameter, which might fail the select query but only after the record is already there. Might require more insight into the database schema.

Comment: It would insert into the 'user_log' not the 'login' table.

Answer (score 1):

Forget SQL injection. The system can be considered non-secure based solely on the fact that it is storing non-hashed/non-salted passwords in a login table and a log table.

If someone were to hack into your database, or discover the appropriate SQL injection required to dump some or all of the data, the hacker would have access to all passwords any user ever attempted to use to login to the website.

Just think of the security implications. If you randomly browsed to this website, forgot what password you used, and then tried *all of your common password variations*, this database would retain every last one of them.

Chills. It gives me chills to think code like this is out there.

Comment: "This is a simplification of how the system i build" - OP